# How to make a Registration Page using Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have been trying to make a registration page which will take 3 values `ID`,`NAME`,`Password`. I have some ideas in mind but I was unable to make this project.

Please can somebody through some light on how to make this registration page by using Struts 2.

What am trying to design is first the registration page will be open let it be `index.jsp` after that when the user will do his/her entries if the entries are updated then return statement will be success.

I know how to create view an `index.jsp` but am having some confusion in creating the `execute()` method (`Action` class).

Comment: Do you have some kind of code?

Comment: @Areca Some kind of code is useless until it shows an attempted solution.

Answer (score 2):

The registration page is made using Struts UI tags. These tags allows you to generate HTML content required for the user to enter registration details such as user name, password, gender, date of birth into the page and save it in the user details.

You can follow the tutorial that is using code for registration page: [Struts 2 UI Tags Tutorial](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ui-tags-example-1.html).

Struts example brings you into [Processing Forms](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/processing-forms.html) page. There you can find a tutorial from [examples project](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples).

<sub>Struts2 team has created examples project to help you with code examples and tutorials.</sub>