# Getting no action mapped error in struts 2 application

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, apache-poi

I am trying to return poi excel workbook as a result in struts application while clicked on download button, but it is giving HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [send] associated with context path [/Generator].

**My `web.xml` file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ExcelGenerator</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>download.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
 <display-name>Struts2FileDownload</display-name>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
      </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**My `struts.xml` file is:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
    <package name="Generator" extends="struts-default">
         <action name="send" class="org.home.Send" method="execute">
           <result name="success" type="stream">
             <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
             <param name="inputName">input</param>
             <param name="contentDisposition">application;filename="example.xls"</param>
             <param name="bufferSize">4090</param>
           </result>
         </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

**My project hierarchy is:**

[image]

Comment: Can you also post the download.jsp page code.

Answer (score 1):

No action mapped for the url means that Struts can't find the action config that has a mapping printed by the error message.

Indeed the file `struts.xm` is in `classes` folder under web content root. But it should be on classpath. Move it to Java sources folder or resources, then it will be copied to the right place when you run the application.

Comment: I tried it but in vain, I am new to struts and I wanted to create excel file in action class and return it. Everything in the code seems alright and mapping is also fine.Though it is giving the same error.

Comment: Here you'll find examples and tutorials http://stackoverflow.com/a/36374120/573032